# swagger-ui build broken with angular 13

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, swagger, swagger-ui

Using the https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui to create the swagger ui in angular 13.

```
npm install swagger-ui
```

**Add Swagger UI to the Component:**

```
export class SwaggerUIComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('swaggerContainer') swaggerContainer: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    SwaggerUI({
      url: 'http://localhost:5270/swagger/v1/swagger.json',
      domNode: this.swaggerContainer.nativeElement,
      deepLinking: true,
      presets: [
        SwaggerUI.presets.apis
      ],
    });
  }
}
```

And in your component's HTML:

```
<div #swaggerContainer></div>
```

Link css in angular.json file styles section

```
"node_modules/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui.css"
```

**Exception**

```
./node_modules/swagger-ui/dist/swagger-ui.css.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[2]!./node_modules/swagger-ui/dist/swagger-ui.css - Error: Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
<css input>:200:0: Can't resolve '"data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns=/"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg/" width=/"24/" height=/"24/"><path d=/"M10 6 8.59 7.41 13.17 12l-4.58 4.59L10 18l6-6z/"/></svg>"' in 'C:\6clicks\src\LegalRegTech.Web.Host\node_modules\swagger-ui\dist'
```

Closed issue on github - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/8243